# Entity Framework 6 SQlite Precompile Views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, entity

I have an application built on the following:
    - .NET 4.6.1
    - SQLite 1.0.106
    - Entity Framework 
    - Database first

The database has 20 or so tables, each with 10k-40k rows. There are a lot of foreign keys, resulting in a lot intermingling in the objects and properties.

There are two or three main tables. For most operations involving these, it is necessary to load the entire table. The first time this is done, it takes orders of magnitude longer than the second time. Most tables take 2-3 seconds. One take 15.

I want to precompile views, because I have been led to believe that will speed up the first queries.

A few specific questions

1. Can I expect that precompiling views will speed up the first load up for these tables? Can you explain why or why not?
2. What are the mechanics of compiled views, specifically.
3. How can I precompile the views? I have tried these things, but they do not seem to work

   a. Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition. Depending on which file I right click on to generate views, I get a different error.

   -If I right click on DataModel.Context.cs, I get the following error that I don't know what to do with.

   > "Unable to determine the provider name for the provider factory of
   >   type 'System.Data.SQlite.SQliteFactory'. Make sure the ADO.net
   >   provider is installed or registered in the application config."

   -If I right click on DataModel.edmx, I get the following error. This ADO.net provider is registered in the app.config file, so I don't know what it wants from me.

   > "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
   >   invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6'. Make sure the provider is
   >   registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config
   >   file."

   b. Downloaded T4 template and tried to run it.  An empty views file is generated

   > "Running transformation: System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: A  >null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method on a store     >provider instance of   >type 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory'. The store provider    >might not be functioning correctly."

   c. I tried this guidance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/b18a9d16-e10b-4043-ba91-b632f85a2579. On rebuild I get these errors, which I just don't understand.

   ```
   1>EXEC : error 7004: The required parameter 'mode' is missing.
   1>  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
   1>  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
   1>  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1276,5): error MSB3073: The command ""%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" /nologo /language:CSharp 
   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1276,5): error MSB3073: /mode:ViewGeneration "/inssdl:C:\Source\Repro\Repro\bin\Debug\ReproDataModel.ssdl"
   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1276,5): error MSB3073: "/incsdl:C:\Source\Repro\Repro\bin\Debug\ReproDataModel.csdl" 
   /inmsl:C:\Source\Repro\Repro\bin\Debug\ReproDataModel.msl" 
   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1276,5): error MSB3073: "/outviews:C:\Source\Repro\Repro\ReproDataModel.Views.cs"" exited with code 123.
   ```

Comment: I'm encountering same problem. I tried everything I could find, but with no luck. I'm not sure if there is way to fix this, or if EF Power Tools just doesn't work with SQLite.

Comment: I'm surprised this post hasn't been garbage-collected. But you are correct. Power tools just doesn't really work with SQLite. I also can't find a  clear answer on what performance improvement precompiled views could give with DB first EF6. I did some tests with my basic database and SQL, and if I remember correctly, compiling was saving me about .5-1 second out of about 8 seconds load time.

Comment: Well. In our case, it takes ~30 seconds to run first query with some 5 entities. But only on specific PCs, in development it is ~2 seconds. And precompiled views is only thing we found out that could help. And it is impossible to debug as EF is huge black box.

Comment: EF6 is on GitHub (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6).

Comment: Also, I think the best idea I had was to make my own T4 template. The guidance I posted above didn't get me to a canned solution, but it is sufficient to put together a T4 template. I started it, but didn't get very far before deciding to switch to some deployable version of SQL to get full EF power. I eventually learned that there are not good, deployable versions of SQL, nor good, lightweight, SQL db editors. I also learned that, as mentioned, I was not going to get a heroic improvement in load time. So I gave up. But if you want to go down that road, let me know if I can help.

Comment: I did raise an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/523 .Doesn't seem it is easy problem to solve.